# Windows 7 not recognizing my tablet for android development

Tags: android, windows-7, device-driver

I have recently imported a tablet from china (where else haha) and the driver is not recognizing it. I have tryied installing the google driver for it but windows 7 still isnt installing any driver. The tablet specs are:

- Brand: MEIYING
- API: 4.0.3
- Kernel Version: 3.0.8+
- Build Number: rk29sdk mid-eng 4.0.3 ILM47K eng.root.20120209.162346 test-keys
- Model number: MID

If there is any other information you need just ask.

**EDIT:** Since there is no driver for this tablet what is the best way to debug the tablet without rooting?

Comment: Make sure you are installing ADB drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you wont find any drivers for Tablet from smaller Companys or they simply don't work. I would suggest you to use the wireless debugging, which is built in in Android ICS+. You can simply turn it on under development in the settings. Just run 'adb connect [your IP Adress over lokal WIFI]' and you should be good to go :)

Edit:
I once had the same problem. I just did not find any driver. Hope youll be luckier. But since you can use adb over wifi this shouldnt be the problem

Edit2:
I discovered that adb over wifi isn't built in in Android. I just had a custom ROM which supported this. You need root access to use it over wifi.

Comment: Any other options for debugging without a driver that do not require root?